# Scandir in a Recursive function

Tags: php, function, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function to display a directory tree with `scandir()`.

I've tried the code below, but it keeps sending

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object

What am I doing wrong?

```
$dir = scandir('.');

function scan($location) {
    
    foreach($location as $path) {

        if (is_dir($path)) {

            scan($path);
        }

        else {
            echo $path.'<br>';
        }
    }
}

scan($dir);
```

Comment: `scan($path);` should be `scan(scandir($path));` because `scan()` requires an array and you currently give a string (`$path`).

Comment: @Syscall I've tried the entry you suggested, but it made the function infinite.

Answer (score 1):

In the first call, you send the result of `scandir()`, which is an array (or false). Then, in the recursive calls, you send a string.

Then, you need to take care about the result of [`scandir()`](https://php.net/scandir). It returns `.` and `..` : the current directory, and the parent directory.

Your code with `scandir()` inside the function:

```php
function scan($location) 
{
    $dirs = scandir($location);
    foreach($dirs as $path) {

        if ($path == '.' || $path == '..') continue;
        
        if (is_dir($path)) {

            scan($path);
        }

        else {
            echo $path.'<br>'; // 
        }
    }
}

scan('.');
```

Also, you could take a look on [the DirectoryIterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and [the FilesystemIterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php).

Comment: I think you'll also want to echo `$path` inside the `if (is_dir($path))` so that you see the directories as well. Then you'll need to come up with a way to keep track of how many tabs you want at the beginning of each line to make it appear like a tree. But this answer should solve the initial problem.

Comment: Thank you! Both your and @amiad's solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

`scandir` return `.` (this dir) and `..` (parent dir) too. You should ignore them.

```php
if ($path != '.' && $path != '..' && is_dir($path)){
    scan(scandir($path));
}
```

Comment: Excellent. You can mark this answer.